# Dynamic List in Flutter for Json

Tags: json, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm working with some complex json in dart, and I have an issue creating objects before I know what type they'll be.

I appreciate the suggestions, but I don't think I completely understand. In the given answer:

```
var entity = Model();
  castToEntity(entity, {'test': 10});
```

Don't I need to know that it will be a Model class?
What if I have the below two classes:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, includeIfNull: false)
class Location {
  String id;
  String resourceType;
Location({@required this.id, this.resourceType})
factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LocationFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
}
class Reference {
  String reference;
  String resourceType;
Location({@required this.reference, this.resourceType}
factory Reference.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ReferenceFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ReferenceToJson(this);
}
```

And then I query the server, and I don't know what kind of class it will be. It could be a Location, or a Reference, or if it's a list, it could be multiple of both, and I don't know until I've requested it.

```
var myBundle = Bundle.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
```

Each "myBundle.entry" is another resource. I'd like to be able to use information from that resource to define itself. So I could do something like:

```
myBundle.entry.resourceType newResource = new myBundle.entry.resourceType();
```

What I'm doing right now is sending it to a function that has all of the possible options predefined:

```
var newResource = ResourceTypes(myBundle.entry[i].resource.resourceType,
                    myBundle.entry[i].resource.toJson());

dynamic ResourceTypes(String resourceType, Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (resourceType == 'Location') return (new Location.fromJson(json));
  if (resourceType == 'Reference') return (new Reference.fromJson(json));
}
```

It was said that there's not reflection in dart, so I didn't know any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible since Dart doesn't have `Reflection` like c#, the most close that I can imagine, is using an abstract class that enforces your entity to implement `fromJson`, and, in that method, you read the Map and put values into fields, like the code below:

```
abstract class Serializable {
  void fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data);
}

class Model implements Serializable {

  int test;
  @override
  void fromJson(data) {
    test = data['test'];
  }
}

Serializable castToEntity(Serializable entity, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  return entity..fromJson(data);
}
```

Now, when you read you database and have the Map, you can call a method generic like:

```
var entity = Model();
  castToEntity(entity, {'test': 10});

  print(entity.test);
```

Where entity is an empty model.

**Note:** Your fields on entity, cannot be final, since `fromJson` is an instance method and not a factory method.

Comment: And make all your entities implement that interface, you can put "toJson" method in that interface too...